# Juypter notebook shows blank page

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I upgraded conda packages using:

```
Conda upgrade —all
```

After that Juypter Notebook shows blank screen in Google Chrome.

1. I did system restore.
2. Updated Anaconda.
3. I removed Jupyter Notebook and reinstalled it.
4. Updated Google Chrome.
5. Cleared browsing history and cookies.

But nothing worked.
Any suggestions to solve this issue?

Comment: I just encountered the same issue and found out the file I was trying to open is not a **.ipynb** file, it was a **.pdf** file.

Answer (score 29):

I was getting the blank page with the URL http://localhost:8888/tree .. when I changed it to 127.0.0.1:8888/tree it shows me the usual home page.

Comment: It works but why?

Comment: I had the same problem of blank page. Changed *tree?* to *lab?* that restored status quo.

Answer (score 18):

I encountered the same problem, but in my case I'm installing it using pip instead.

When you open the jupyter notebook on you browser (regardless of browser) and it shows you blank jupyter, try to press (`CTRL + Shift + R`) it will refresh the page and clear the cache in the page. It works for me after I keep installing and uninstalling jupyter.

Do note that notebook version `5.7.8` is not working for me, so I pip uninstall notebook and `pip install notebook==5.7.4` instead.

Comment: For me, the refreshing trick (`CTRL + Shift + R`) works and I am using notebook 5.7.8 on Windows 10 with Python 3.7.3 and Chrome as browser.

Comment: Does not help for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try `conda update -all` instead upgrade and give it a try.

If that doesn't work try: `conda upgrade notebook`

Comment: If that didnt work you can try to force open in chrome. Run `jupyter lab --generate-config`. open the config file generated (the generate-config command will give the path to this file). Add the following line to the config file:
`c.LabApp.browser = r'"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\Chrome.exe" --app=%s'`

Comment: It already opens in Chrome, the problem it shows a blank page.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue and after some time, realised that AdBlock was blocking the localhost on Google chrome. If I toggle off Adblock while on Jupyter, refresh the page , the notebook then shows on Google chrome

Comment: Thanks this worked for me. If you have AdBlocker on your site, just disable it and it will work.

Answer (score -2):

I assume you are getting this error " http://localhost:8888/tree" where you can't find any of your files. I was having the same problem. When I dig into the details found out I was using notebook version 6.0.3 and the latest version at the moment was 6.3.0. This happens when you update few of the packages and jupyter notebook version is not updated. After this, it took me a minute to solve the error.

**Solution:** Just go to anaconda prompt and update your notebook by typing the command **pip install --upgrade notebook**.